# Solr server security

Tags: solr, solrj

I have a Solr server that returns search results to users via Ajax requests. The request all looks like this: http://abc.com/core1/select?q=...

Now I just realized this would expose my search server to potential "bad" guys. I can have basic authentication on the jetty Solr server but it would block people from calling the search server.

My question is what is the common strategy to fix this ? Should I use the Solrj java client library from my Tomcat webserver to search first and then return the results to users, also firewall the access to the search server completely  ?  Any other way to get around it ?

Comment: Depending on your setup ..  The way I do this is by setting up the URL in a specific manner where if it's encoded incorrectly, the PHP/ASP etc will fail.  The way I am set up is as follows:  SOLR on Tomcat 6 ...  PORT:8080 --> NON ACCESSIBLE FROM EXTERNAL IP (That's Important!)  A highly customised version of SolrPhpClient.  My URLs look like http://example.com/search/this+widget   --  You cannot go to my site and search using http://example.com/search/index.php?q=this%20widget ...  In order to protect it, just make sure that your SOLR setup isn't accessible except for locally ...

Comment: good suggestion. After playing around with all kinds of Json parser and clients, I have decided to use the Apache pooling http client to stream the json response from the search server back to the client. The search server access is restricted by firewall. Thank you,

Comment: Maybe you can add your own answer and accept it.